# Storing data locally - doesn't work?

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-architect

As you can see. If I were to update a FIELD, i would receive an ALERT which would display me the TESTVALUEform my model.  The first time it would be empty has my Store would be empty. But the 2nd time it should display me ROGER.  but it does not. It is has my store was never synced.

Can somone help me ?

Here is my code :

Controller which receive the updated data (checked, it does receive the event)

```
Ext.define('Prototype.controller.MyController', {
extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

config: {
    control: {
        "textfield": {
            change: 'onTextfieldChange'
        }
    }
},

onTextfieldChange: function(textfield, newValue, oldValue, eOpts) {
    Ext.getStore('localdb').load();
    var test = Ext.getStore('localdb').last().get('testValue');
    console.log(test);
    Ext.getStore('localdb').add({testvalue: 'ROGER'});
    Ext.getStore('localdb').sync();
}

});
```

Model :

```
Ext.define('Prototype.model.LocalData', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

config: {
    identifier: {
        type: 'uuid'
    },
    proxy: {
        type: 'localstorage',
        id: 'test1'
    },
    fields: [
        {
            name: 'testValue'
        }
    ]
}
});
```

Store :

```
Ext.define('Prototype.store.LocalStore', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

requires: [
    'Prototype.model.LocalData'
],

config: {
    model: 'Prototype.model.LocalData',
    storeId: 'localdb',
    syncRemovedRecords: false,
    proxy: {
        type: 'localstorage',
        id: 'test1'
    }
}
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Controller should be like this

```
Ext.getStore('localdb').load();
var test = Ext.getStore('localdb').last().get('testValue');
console.log(test);
var tested = Ext.create('Prototype.model.LocalData');
tested.set('testValue','roger');
Ext.getStore('localdb').add(tested);
Ext.getStore('localdb').sync();
```

I was not writing the data correctly -_-'

Comment: Yes, you have to create object with a model. You are only able to sync that kind of data directly in a store

Answer (score 1):

Before performing your sync, add `record.setDirty()` to your record.

Comment: It was not the issue, thank you!

Comment: Anything in the console? Warnings when you're adding the record? Also in Chrome you can check storage page to see your local db in run-time. This might help troubleshoot it.

Comment: The problem was i was not adding data correctly, see my own anwser to my question :P thanks for you help :)